# How to count response time max avg for nginx logs?

Tags: shell-script, awk, scripting

I want count the response time max and average from `nginx` logs, based on hourly or minutes per api...

`nginx.log` sample:

```
10.1.1.1 - - [25/Aug/2019:05:26:30 +0700] "POST /v2/api/find/outlet/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2667 "-" "okhttp/3.12.0" "118.215.153.47" 0.178 0.178 .
10.1.1.1 - - [25/Aug/2019:05:26:30 +0700] "POST /v2/api/find/outlet/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2847 "-" "okhttp/3.12.0" "189.246.151.188" 0.177 0.178 .
10.1.1.1 - - [25/Aug/2019:05:27:52 +0700] "GET /v2/api/menu/category HTTP/1.1" 401 40 "-" "okhttp/3.12.0" "139.194.84.246" 0.007 0.007 .
10.1.1.1 - - [25/Aug/2019:05:27:52 +0700] "GET /v2/api/user/point HTTP/1.1" 200 152 "-" "okhttp/3.12.0" "202.80.217.172" 0.028 0.028 .
10.1.1.1 - - [25/Aug/2019:05:27:52 +0700] "GET /v2/api/user/destination HTTP/1.1" 200 169 "-" "okhttp/3.12.0" "36.91.42.35" 0.019 0.019 .
10.1.1.1 - - [25/Aug/2019:05:28:52 +0700] "POST /v2/api/transaction/inquiry HTTP/1.1" 200 503 "-" "okhttp/3.12.0" "36.89.234.129" 0.374 0.374 .
10.1.1.1 - - [25/Aug/2019:05:28:52 +0700] "POST /v2/api/transaction/confirm HTTP/1.1" 200 874 "-" "okhttp/3.12.0" "36.89.234.129" 0.394 0.394 .
10.1.1.1 - - [25/Aug/2019:05:28:52 +0700] "GET /v2/api/user/point HTTP/1.1" 200 152 "-" "okhttp/3.12.0" "114.5.147.117" 0.024 0.024 .
10.1.1.1 - - [25/Aug/2019:05:28:52 +0700] "GET /v2/api/menu/category HTTP/1.1" 403 40 "-" "okhttp/3.12.0" "139.194.84.246" 0.003 0.003 .
```

expectation sample below:

```
date                       |  api                               | max| avg

25/Aug/2019:05:26 /v2/api/find/outlet             2847 2757
25/Aug/2019:05:27 /v2/api/menu/category HTTP/1.1               1847 1757
25/Aug/2019:05:28 /v2/api/menu/category HTTP/1.1               1147 1257
```

I already try with this `awk` but only got the average:

```
awk '/25\/Aug\/2019:18/ {c++} END{print c}' access.log
```

Thanks

Comment: did you have a look at https://goaccess.io ? It's a nice log parser and might be of use for you.

Comment: If `expectation sample` is the expected output given your posted sample input then please explain where the max and avg values are coming from and when there's 2 "category": lines but only 1 "outlet" line and no "point", "destination", "inquiry" or "confirm" lines in the output. If "expectation sample" is your expected output and it's not 100% accurate wrt the exact output you'd expect given the input you provided then fix it.

Answer (score 2):

You really ought to use one of the many web server log file analysers (e.g. https://goaccess.io/ as suggested by @Bart.  There's a decent summary of some alternatives at [7 Awesome Open Source Analytics Software For Linux and Unix](https://www.cyberciti.biz/open-source/7-awesome-open-source-analytics-weblog-analysis-softwares/), and google will find you more), but for a quick-and-dirty hack, you could use something like this:

```
awk -v OFS='\t' '
    $0 ~ date { max[$7]+=$(NF-1); count[$7]++ };
    END {
      print "date","api","count","max","avg";
      for (i in max) {
        print date, i, count[i], max[i], max[i]/count[i] }
      }' \
  date="25/Aug/2019" nginx.log
```

Output based on your sample is (note, the fields are separated by tabs, not spaces):

```
date    api     count   max     avg
25/Aug/2019     /v2/api/find/outlet/    2       0.356   0.178
25/Aug/2019     /v2/api/user/destination        1       0.019   0.019
25/Aug/2019     /v2/api/transaction/inquiry     1       0.374   0.374
25/Aug/2019     /v2/api/user/point      2       0.052   0.026
25/Aug/2019     /v2/api/transaction/confirm     1       0.394   0.394
25/Aug/2019     /v2/api/menu/category   2       0.01    0.005
```

BTW, the awk script above is based on the assumption that the response time for a given request is in the 2nd last field (`$(NF-1)`).  I've had to guess here because you haven't told us what logfile format you have configured for your nginx server, or what the last few fields on each line are.

Comment: hi cas thank for your help and reply...